# Canonical transformations - sufficient & neccessary argument

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, poisson-brackets

I see in many textbooks that for a transformation of coordinates  $P=P(q,p,t), Q=Q(q,p,t)$ it is sufficient & neccessary to check: $$[Q_i,Q_j]_{q,p} = 0$$ $$[P_i,P_j]_{q,p} = 0 $$ $$[Q_i,P_j]_{q,p}=\delta_{ij}$$
for the transformation to be canonical, as follows from:
$$[f,g]_{q,p} = [f,g]_{Q,P}.$$
It seems to be trivial and it is always given without any proof, but why is that? I don't see why it is sufficient.

Comment: Did you use the chain rule of PBs, and the trivial determinant involved?

Comment: I don't quite understand what is PB nor the determinant, could you elaborate?

Comment: You are changing variables from upper case to lower case variables: a multi-variable change, dominated by a Jacobian determinant. Work out how Poisson brackets transform; it is probably in your textbook.

Answer (score 0):

The *fundamental Poisson brackets are invariant under canonical transformation.* It follows from here that
$$[\zeta,\zeta]_\eta=\tilde{M}JM$$
the invariance is a necessary and sufficient condition for the transformation matrix to be symplectic. The invariance of the fundamental Poisson brackets is thus in all ways equivalent to the symplectic condition for a canonical transformation.

I haven't get into much detail, As you can find the details in Goldstein's book. :)